# 戻り値が NotNull であることをアノテーションで表現できますか？

Tags: java, annotations

List を返すメソッドにおいて null を返さないことを保証したいと考えています。
実装上は null ではなく Collections.emptyList() を返すだけですが、null を返さないことをアノテーションで表現することは可能でしょうか。

IDE との何らかの連携があるとより良いのですが、自分の観測範囲ではわかりませんでした。

Answer (score 11):

`null` を返さないことを保証するアノーテーションをしたいときには、[JSR-305](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305) を導入するのが一番良いです。  (ここではこのアノテーションを 「`@NonNull`系」と呼ばせてください)

#### JSR-305: 導入と記述方法

導入は、 [外部 jar としてjsr305-X.X.X.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.0) をクラスパスに追加する、もしくは [Maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.code.findbugs%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jsr305%22) なら以下のようにします。

```
<dependency>
    <groupId><code class="findbugs"></code></groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

そのうえで、メソッドの返り値が `null` ではないことを示すためには、ソースコード上で、アノテーションを以下のように付記します。

```
public @Nonnull static String fold( Iterator<?> iterator) {
   ...
   return nonNullString;    
}

@Nonnull 
public static String join( Iterator<?> iterator) {
   ...
   return nonNullString;    
}
```

#### @Nonnull 系アノーテーションの生態

`@Nonnull` 系のアノテーションは JDK に付属しておらず、どちらかというと JavaEE の一部という扱いです。どれが標準かはっきりせず、 JSR-305 以外にも `@Nonnull`系アノーテーションが様々なパッケージに存在しています。

- JSR-305 : `javax.annotation.Nonnull`
- JSR-303 : `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`
- IDEA : `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull`
- Eclipse : `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull`
- Android : `android.support.annotation.NonNull`
- CheckerFramework: `org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull`

これらすべて、アノテート目的は同じで、名前が違うぐらいのものです。プロジェクトの構成によって、上記のクラスのどれかを使うことになるでしょう。

#### IDE: IntelliJ IDEA でのサポート

IntelliJ IDEA の `null` チェックサポートはおそらく IDE の中でも [一番歴史が古く](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/03/detecting-probably-npes/)、かなり高機能なので、 開発環境に高度な `null` チェック機能を求めておられるのなら、IDEA は外せません。IDEA は、歴史的な理由で、独自に `@NotNull` アノテーションを持ってもいます。 IDE がサポートする機能は `javax.annotation.Nonnull` に対するものより、少し広いので、 IDEAをメインに使用する場合 アノテーションに `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull` を選択するのはアリです。

```
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
...
public @NotNull String fold( Iterator<?> iterator) {
   ...
   return it;   
}
```

他に、 IDEA には、メニューの [`Analyze > Infer Nullity`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/inferring-nullity.html) と選択することで、自動で `@Nullable`, `@NotNull` アノテーションをつけてくれる機能があり、便利です。

#### IDE: Eclipse でのサポート

Eclipse は基本、 `javax` 及び Eclipse 独自のアノーテーションを認識します。[コンパイラの警告/エラーセッティング](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm&anchor=null_annotation_names) を変更することで IDE が反応するようになります。機能的には、最低限をそつなくサポートしている感じで、他の `@Nonnull` 系アノーテーションの導入も容易です。もっと突っ込んだ警告がほしければ、[FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) を導入すべきでしょう。

Eclipse の面白い点としては、 [`@NonNullByDefault`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fannotation%2FNonNullByDefault.html) というアノーテーションのサポートがあることで、これによりパッケージを対象に、 `@NonNull` が付いた状態をデフォルトとするといったことができます。強力すぎて警告の数に最初ヒクと思いますが、徹底した管理を求めたいならこれを使うのも良いと思います。

`@NonNullByDefault` は、以下のようにパッケージコメントファイル `package-info.java` の中のパッケージ宣言に対して付けられます。(※ クラスが書かれたソースコードではありません！）

```
/**
* @author XXXXX
 */
@NonNullByDefault
package jp.domain;
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault;
```

#### IDE: Netbeans でのサポート

Netbeans は `@Nonnull`　系アノーテーションを認識し、ソースコード解析を通して警告を発生することができます。設定ダイアログ `Editor > Hint` の、 `Null Pointer Dereference` がその警告になります。

不足があれば、 [Firebugs](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/912/findbugs-tm-plugin) を[ドキュメントに従ってセットアップ](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/code-inspect.html)していけば、十分な静的解析の環境が整うでしょう。

#### 古いプロジェクト向けに

IDE ではありませんですが、[Checker Framework](http://checkerframework.org/) フレームワーク を使っていると、このように書くこともできます。 ([Eclipse Plugin](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/checker-plugin/update-site/)もあります)

```
public /*@NonNull*/ String fold( Iterator<?> iterator) {
   ...
   return it;   
}
```

JDK 1.5 で時が止まっているような古いプロジェクトに、ひっそりと導入することができて、幸せになれる人もいるかもしれません。私はこの書き方好きなんですけどね。

Comment: 詳細な回答ありがとうございます！
IDE の独自拡張があるのですね。
特に最近 Optional の使える Java 8 を書いているので NonNull をデフォルトにする、というのはアリだなあと感じました。戻り値 null は無い方が安全かな、と。
Checker Framework は Type Annotation の使えない頃のプロジェクトでも使えるんですね。ざっと確認しましたが、かなり多機能な印象を受けました。

Answer (score 7):

[JSR-305](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=305)のライブラリをプロジェクトに追加して、`@javax.annotation.Nonnull`とのアノテーションが下記通り使用できます：

```
@Nonnull
public List<?> getList() {
    // ...
}
```

JSR-305のライブラリは[Maven中央レポジトリからダウンロード](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/)できます。

Netbeans、EclipseやIntelliJの最近のバージョンはJSR-305のアノテーションをサポートして、違反警告を出します。

Comment: JSR-305 良さげですね。`mvn findbugs:check` で確認できる点が非常に気に入りました。

Comment: そうですね。とても便利です。Googleも[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild)とのライブラリでJSR-305使っています。